# Virtual multi-parameter attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have a rails model that stores hours of operation as a postgres `tstzrange`, to accomplish this with rails I use the virtual attributes `opens_at` and `closes_at`. Currently I have database columns for these attributes that don't save anything, but I have to have them because rails will complain about not knowing the class of the attribute receiving the multiple parameter assignment unless it maps to a data type.

There are a few extra moving pieces here that don't really matter so they weren't included.

I guess what I'm asking is: Is there a way to remove the DB columns `closes_at` and `opens_at` and still be able to submit a datetime over a web for and have rails serialize it? Can I somehow use something like `attr_accessible` to point to a data type?

```
class OperationDay

  def closes_at=(close)
    close = to_2012(close)
    Rails.logger.debug "OD-#{self.id} set closes_at to #{close}"
    @closes_at = close
    check_wrap
  end

  def opens_at=(open)
    open = to_2012(open)
    Rails.logger.debug "OD-#{self.id} set opens_at to #{open}"
    @opens_at = open
    check_wrap
  end

  def opens_at
    return self.open if @opens_at.nil?
    to_2012(@opens_at)
  end

  def closes_at
    return self.close if @closes_at.nil?
    to_2012(@closes_at)
  end
end
```